# Call init-method of a session-scoped bean from a singleton bean

Tags: java, spring, scope

I have a session scoped bean which is injected into a singleton bean using a proxy.
From the singleton bean I need to call a certain init-method of the session scoped bean, which needs the singleton bean as parameter.
Furthermore I can not change the source of the session scoped bean.

To elaborate the case:
The singleton bean is a Service and the session scoped bean is a Vaadin4Spring eventbus, for which I need to call the method `eventBus.subscribe(this)`.

There seems to be no way to check, if I am already subscribed and I must not call subscribe twice on a certain  `eventBus`  instance.

Is there a way to tell Spring to call `eventBus.subscribe(this)` when the proxy links to an `eventBus` instance for the first time?

Comment: Uh! SessionBeans are instanticated when a request is incomming. A Singleton is initialized when the applications starts. You can not recieve request before the application (and their Singletons) is initalized!

Comment: Possible with Spring, because Spring will inject a proxy, which will route the access to the correct instance of the bean.

Comment: You could add @Lazy to the Singleton!

Comment: Actually, session scoped beans are instantiated when the session starts, request scoped beans are instantiated when a request comes in.

Comment: @dunni Never seen a SessionScopeBean without a request. Even serialized sessions are deserialized when a request (having the matching passivated sessionid) is incomming.

Comment: Of course, the first request will start a session. But a session scoped bean won't be instantiated on each incoming request (i understood your statement that way).

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just go the other way round, inject the service into your eventbus, and call `this.subscribe(serviceBean)` in a `@PostConstruct` annotated method in the eventbus? Then it would only be called once when the eventbus is constructed.

Comment: That's what I would do, if I could control the code of eventbus...but as stated in my question, I can't. Maybe I should subtype the EventBus class...

Comment: Ah sorry, forgot that.

Answer (score -1):

You could add [@Lazy](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html) to the Singleton. You do not need the Proxy.

Comment: How should that help me, if my service is singleton and the eventBus is not?